# Vuex module not working when importing a custom axios instance

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I have declared an action in a Vuex module:

```
storeBudgets(store: ActionContext<State, any>) {
    return axiosAuth.get('/budget')
        .then((res) => {
            store.commit('setBudgets', res.data.budgets);
        });
}
```

Where axiosAuth is a custom instance of axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import store from './store/index';

const axiosAuth = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
});


axiosAuth.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers['x-access-token'] = store.getters.getUserToken;
    return config;
});

export default axiosAuth;
```

I am using this axios instance in other vuex store modules without any issues, but for this specific action in this specific module, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: rawModule is undefined
```

The error goes away as soon as I comment the reference to axiosAuth.

I think the issue is related to the fact that I am referencing the store in the axios interceptor, since also commenting the `config.headers` line makes the application load without any issues.

I am migrating this logic from a JavaScript project in a TypeScript codebase and didn't have any issues with the former implementation.

- Is this something related to TypeScript transpiling?
- Which alternatives could I use instead of the interceptor to set the JWT token in the header of my HTTP requests?

Comment: Where's the rest of the error? Where are you attempting to use `rawModule`?

Comment: @Phil that is the error and rawModule is something internal to Vuex/Vuejs code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is how TypeScript tries to transpile the imports of dependencies.

I am just guessing, but I had a reference to the store in the axios file, and a reference to axios in one of the vuex store modules.
This might have created some kind of circular reference loop that ends up with throwing an error.

To solve my problem, I moved the setup of the axios interceptor after the vuex store is created, in the `store.ts` file.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

import axiosAuth from "@/axios-auth";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const vuexStore = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {

    },
    modules: {
        // ...
    },
});

axiosAuth.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers['x-access-token'] = vuexStore.getters.getUserToken;
    return config;
});

export default vuexStore;
```

I am not sure if this is the cleanest solution possible, but I am quite happy as it solved my main issue.

Comment: Well done, basically the rationale of solving this is to put any piece of code that reference the store within the store.ts itself. Again I feel that there may be a cleaner solution somewhere

Comment: @ExisZhang Have you found the cleaner solution?